# Observer never called

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsnotification

I have two functions

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("personalDataDidLoad", object: self, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {_ in
            print("Received notification")
            self.showPersonalData()
        }

        loadPersonalData()
    }



func loadPersonalData() {
    //load data
    print("personal data loaded")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("personalDataDidLoad", object: nil)
```

but for some reason this outputs

```
 personal data loaded
```

instead of the expected

```
 personal data loaded
 Received notification
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I don't see it right now....

I also tried `addObserver` with `selector: "showPersonalData:"` but this throws an unrecognized selector exception..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the 2nd parameter in `postNotificationName` and `addObserverForName`: `object`. When you add an observer, and pass a non-nil `object` value, this means that the observer block will run **when a notification comes from that object, and from that object only**.
However, when you fire the notification, you do `object: nil`. So your notification is ignored.

On the other hand, passing a `nil` value for `object` means, "I want to receive this notification regardless of who sends it".

So you need to make sure the object value is the same in both places: either `self` or `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use `addObserverForName(_:object:queue:usingBlock:)`?

Try this instead:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, "personalDataDidLoadNotification:", name: "personalDataDidLoad" object: nil)
    loadPersonalData()
}

func loadPersonalData() {
    //load data
    print("personal data loaded")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("personalDataDidLoad", object: nil)
}

func personalDataDidLoadNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("notification recieved")
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it throws an unrecognised selector error. Which in itself is weird of course, but I've got it working now with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to the title question (but not this example) but will hopefully help others in the situation I have been in for the last 3 hours:

Make sure your notificationcenter observer is added inside a class that has a persisted instance. I created the observer inside a class that was called as e.g. MyClass().setupNotification inside a local method of another class.

This meant the observer was immediately deleted and didnt persist against any instance.

Schoolboy error - but hope this helps others searching for this.